# how to check in twig if a form field has label

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

when a form field is generated via an iteration:

```
{% for field in form %}
{{ form_widget(field); }}
{% endform %}
```

then it will encapsulates a div block surround the field's input type, and a label (if it has a label).

I want to seperate this into label, and widget:

```
      <div class="form-group">                
        {% if field.vars.label is not null %}
          {{ form_label(field) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_widget(field) }}
      </div>
```

but the field.vars.label is always null. BTW when I generates without the condition, then it's shows labels correctly.

How do I get the label's value for the condition check?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Twig uses `name` if `label` is not set. So your check should be like `{% if field.vars.label is not empty and field.vars.name is not empty %}`. And that also looks like what you're trying to achieve is described in [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) cookbook.

Comment: You're right. The problem is, that all field has name. I'm still don't know how the form_widget decides which fields will have label and which not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the label to false and the form_label() twig function will automatically ignore it.

Here's a code snippet from the form_div_layout.html.twig file (see line 2):

```
{%- block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}
```

Comment: It leads me to a compromise :) I would like to avoid from change the formbuilder, 'til now. Thank you, I should accept this solution

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables) of Form Variables Reference,

Try with:

```
    {% if field.vars.attr.label is not null %}
```

instead of:

```
    {% if field.vars.label is not null %}
```

Comment: Method "label" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist. That is the result :(

Comment: @Roland sorry, try with `field.attr.label` also

Comment: sorry again @Roland, instead of the source code, you should access to the label field via `field.vars.attr.label`. Check my answer update

Comment: Evgeny Soynov has right, those fields have no label, and uses "name", but it's not clear how can the form_widget decide wich field has to have label, and which not